# Mapreduce java heap space error during reduce phase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple mapreduce job for building a tfidf index but I always end up with java heap space error when reducer is at approx. 70%. I tried different approaches, using all sorts of structures, telling my job to use more memory in the command and running my job on smaller sample but nothing changed even slightly. I am at the end of my ideas so I would appreciate any tips what is  going on.

Mapper produces right output but reducer always fails due to java heap space error.

This is the command that I am running (I am trying to specify the amount of memory used): `hadoop jar WordCountMPv1.jar -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 -D mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048 --input /user/myslima3/wiki2 --output /user/myslima3/index`

My whole mapreduce code:

```
public class Indexer extends Configured implements Tool {


    /*
     * Vocabulary: key = term, value = index
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> vocab = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private static Map<String, Double> mapIDF = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    private static final int DOC_COUNT = 751300; // total number of documents

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Indexer(), arguments));
    }

    public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {
        protected Comparator() {
            super(Text.class, true);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
            return -a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }

    public static class IndexerMapper extends
            Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();

        // load vocab from distributed cache
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            URI[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf);
            Path getPath = new Path(cacheFiles[0].getPath());

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fs.open(getPath)));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " \t");

                int index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // first token is the line number - term id
                String word = st.nextToken(); // second element is the term
                double IDF = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // third token is the DF

                // compute IDF
                IDF = (Math.log(DOC_COUNT / IDF));
                mapIDF.put(word, IDF);

                // save vocab
                vocab.put(word, index);

            }
        }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // init TF map
            Map<String, Integer> mapTF = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            // parse input string
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), " \t");

            // first element is doc index
            int index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            //sb.append(index + "\t");

            // count term frequencies
            String word;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word = st.nextToken();

                // check if word is in the vocabulary
                if (vocab.containsKey(word)) {
                    if (mapTF.containsKey(word)) {
                        int count = mapTF.get(word);
                        mapTF.put(word, count + 1);
                    } else {
                        mapTF.put(word, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            // compute TF-IDF
            double idf;
            double tfidf;
            int wordIndex;
            for (String term : mapTF.keySet()) {
                int tf = mapTF.get(term);

                if (mapIDF.containsKey(term)) {
                    idf = mapIDF.get(term);

                    tfidf = tf * idf;
                    wordIndex = vocab.get(term);

                    context.write(new IntWritable(wordIndex), new Text(index + ":" + tfidf));
                }

            }               
        }
    }

    public static class IndexerReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>
    {
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {

            // reset vocab and maps to reduce memory
            vocab = null;
            mapIDF = null;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (Text value : values)
            {
                sb.append(value.toString() + " ");
            }

            context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        ArgumentParser parser = new ArgumentParser("TextPreprocessor");

        parser.addArgument("input", true, true, "specify input directory");
        parser.addArgument("output", true, true, "specify output directory");

        parser.parseAndCheck(arguments);

        Path inputPath = new Path(parser.getString("input"));
        Path outputDir = new Path(parser.getString("output"));

        // Create configuration.
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        // add distributed file with vocabulary
        DistributedCache
                .addCacheFile(new URI("/user/myslima3/vocab.txt"), conf);

        // Create job.
        Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
        job.setJarByClass(IndexerMapper.class);

        // Setup MapReduce.
        job.setMapperClass(IndexerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IndexerReducer.class);

        // Sort the output words in reversed order.
        job.setSortComparatorClass(Comparator.class);


        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // Specify (key, value).
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Input.
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        // Output.
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        // Delete output directory (if exists).
        if (hdfs.exists(outputDir))
            hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);

        // Execute the job.
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: stacktrace

```
15/04/06 10:54:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:54:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 25% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:54:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 31% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:54:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:54:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 55% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:54:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 58% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 69% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 82% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 96% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/04/06 10:55:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 29%
15/04/06 10:55:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 36%
15/04/06 10:55:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 48%
15/04/06 10:55:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 61%
15/04/06 10:55:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 68%
15/04/06 10:55:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 71%
15/04/06 10:55:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1427101801879_0658_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
```

Comment: Can you update with the size of the data along with the error message

Comment: As for the data - I tried it with 1GB and 300MB of data inside couple of text files. The error message says just FAIL: Java heap space when reducer gets to 70& (on both data samples...)

Comment: and how about your cluster size? how much memory did you give for that?

Comment: I am not sure. I do not have detailed information about the cluster. But there are some other MapReduce jobs coping with far more data than this that  runs without any problems...

Comment: it runs in parallel??

Comment: No, jobs are in queue and run one after each other..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my specifying larger number of reducers and implementing a combiner.

Comment: Hi Can you please suggest me changes i am too facing the same problem here is the link [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186845/error-java-heap-space-in-reducer-phase) [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely at the StringBuffer that gets appended in the reducer.  You don't specify an initial size which (I think) defaults to 16.  As it grows it needs to copy itself into a larger and larger buffer so you end up with buffers of length 16, 32, 48, 64, ... (not sure about the growth amount, but you get the picture).  Anyway, a large number of values passed into the reducer can cause a lot of memory to be used and garbage collection can handle most of that until the StringBuffer gets so large that it can't grow.  In other words, this doesn't scale that well.

Given that this is your chosen algorithm, however, I can only suggest you try giving a really large initial size to see if you can get lucky and force a growth that happens to fit in the available memory.

Failing that, you might be able to create a special OutputFormat that's able to concatenate values as they're written and creating a new line when the key changes, but I haven't thought that one all the way through.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried initializing the StringBuilder with some initial capacity (new StringBuilder(4096) or higher) but it did not solve the memory issue

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that you're trying to concatenate a large number of values that don't fit.  Maybe write a line for every 1000 (?) values and then have a pass over the files after map reduce to merge the multi-line entries?

Comment: But each value that I am passing from the mapper belongs to another line in a reducer, I cannot put them together inside map phase. They do not belong together...